# Authentication problem with google drive API in python

Tags: python, google-api

I have a small script copied from Google, it is supposed to upload a file to my appDataFolder at google drive,
When run for the first time it asks for the authentications and I grant permission for it

```
import os.path
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    # Create the service
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    file_metadata = {
        'title': 'token_lol.json',
        'parents': [{
            'id': 'appDataFolder'
        }]
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload('token_lol.json',
                            mimetype='application/json',
                            resumable=True)
    service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()
    #print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then When I try to upload the file I get this error:

```
HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: 
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}]">
```

It only works when I use this SCOPE : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
But according to Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/appdata#python) it should work with this SCOPE : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018387/google-drive-api-how-to-create-a-file-in-appdatafolder?rq=1)
You need to add these 2 SCOPES together:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).